# Mix of solid and dashed line graph in R plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am hoping to make a graph with a solid line (actual data), then a dashed line (projected data) in plotly.

Something like this, but in `plotly`:

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

#data
df <- tibble(type = c("Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Projected", "Projected", "Projected"),
             year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021),
             values = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4))

#ggplot version
ggplot(df %>% filter(type == "Actual"), aes(year, values)) +
  geom_line() + #actual data
  geom_line(data = df %>% filter(year >= 2018), aes(year, values), linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(type == "Actual"), aes(year, values), size = 3) +  
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(type == "Projected"), aes(year, values), size = 3)

#non working plotly
plot_ly(df %>% filter(type == "Actual"), x = ~year, y = ~values, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers') %>%
  add_trace(df %>% filter(type == "Projected"), x = ~year, y = ~values, name = 'trace 1', dash = 'dot') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Year'),
         yaxis = list (title = 'Value')) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero"))
```

I know I can use `ggplotly`, but the tooltips are nicer in `plotly` for what I am trying to do.

There is a warning message about the use of 'dash' with 'scatter' objects, but I am just following the example on the tutorial page: https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/

> Warning message: 'scatter' objects don't have these attributes: 'dash'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

plot_ly() %>%
  # a trace with all the data, dashed
  add_trace(data = df,  x = ~year, y = ~values,
            name = 'Projected', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
            line = list(shape = 'linear', color = 'black', width= 4, dash = 'dash'))%>%
  # a trace that overwrites the actual
  add_trace(data = df %>% filter(type == "Actual"),  x = ~year, y = ~values,
            name = 'Actual', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
            line = list(shape = 'linear', color = 'black', width= 4, dash = 'solid'))%>%
  # remove legend
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]